# Why does margin-left not work on block elements to the right of float:left images?

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

In the following code, I have an image in a div floated left. And some text in a div that wraps right because of the float on the image div. Both are block level elements.

I know I can add separation between them by applying a margin-right to the image. But why can't I also add separation by applying a left-margin to the text div?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HumanJHawkins/r5p3197t/8/

```css
body {
  margin: 5vw;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 4vw;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.thingImage {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.thingImage img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.thingDesc {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Things List</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="thingImage">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/RZMY6kCf/bw-Dog-Sleepy.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="thingDesc">
    <h2>Thing 1</h2>
    <p>Thing one is the first thing.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="thingImage">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/wj0Ghw3r/desaturated-Monkey.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="thingDesc">
    <h2>Thing 2</h2>
    <p>Thing two is the second thing.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="thingImage">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/PrbcqXHT/desaturated-Spider.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="thingDesc">
    <h2>Thing 3</h2>
    <p>Thing one is the third thing.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the float overlap the margin, try to increase it slowly to notice this

Comment: I already seen this strange comportement also, your margin-left is over the content of the image. If you do a bigger margin left than your image width your margin will appears. I don't really understand the uses.. that's due to your "float:left"